# How do I create Visio Stencils with horizontal text and rotating arrows?

Tags: visio

I am trying to create a set of custom stencils, and am having issues finding a couple of things.

I want to create a shape that is a circle with an arrow coming out the top, and a letter in the middle.  I need it to do two things:

1. When rotating the shape, the text needs to remain horizontal.
2. When rotating the shape, the center of rotation needs to be the center of the circle, not the center of the circle/arrow shape.

I tried using a transform equation on the stencil which worked fine in the stencil editor, but doesn't hold the text horizontal when I place the shape/stencil into a document.

Any tips or links that can help me achieve these?  #1 is most important; I can probably find a way to make #2 happen just by resizing the stencil.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found two things...

To keep the text in the center, you have to add all the parts of your shape and group them.  Then you add the text and move it (using the text selection tool) to the place you want it (in this case, the center of the circle).  Then go to Developer->Show ShapeSheet->Text Transform (you may have to add this section) and under TextAngle, enter the following formula:

```
IF(BITXOR(FlipX, FlipY), Angle, -Angle)
```

To make your shape rotate around the center of the circle, click the shape.  When you see the rotation tool, look to where it ends in the shape and drag it where you want it.  There is probably a way to do this via ShapeSheet, but this works for me.

Now when I drop this on the page, I can rotate the arrow to point in the direction I want, but the circle stays where I put it and the letter is horizontal to the rest of the drawing.

Pics (note the x/y offset is due to paint; it rotates perfectly around the circle in Visio):

Default Master: [image: Default Master]

Placed on page and rotated: [image]

I would love some further suggestions on how this can be done.  I have a hard time finding comprehensive instructions for Visio.